# Reduce numbers of request Firebase

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to know what cost a reads on Cloud Firestore.
For example, the app is loading an object of a collection and all fields into it. Does it cost 1 read for the object or does it cost 10 reads since there are 10 fields in this object (name, image link, description, uuid, createDates, price , price, price 3 etc) ?

If the answer is 10 (which I supposed it is), there is a possibility to reduce reads by deleting the fields I don't need when using my app (createdates, uuid for example).

Is there any problems doing that?

Also, can I group some of the fields together? (let's say `price(string)=price1/price2/price3` and then in my app I say `price1` is the first number of price, `price2` is the one in the middle and so on.

Will this reduce the reads by 3 for the price?

Thank you very much for theses explanations

Answer (score 4):

Firestore pricing is based on document (object) reads: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing with a minimum charge of one document for every query, even if there are no results.

Since documents contain the key/value pair fields (https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/data-model) you should only get charged per document, not per field.

Of course, other costs may come into play, as the documentation notes that larger documents can be slower to retrieve (a cost of latency) and of course larger documents will use more network bandwidth, which can incur a cost in some cases.

There is other guidance on the pricing page about how to reduce costs for large result sets, via the use of cursors, but the costs are still based on documents.